# erro al subir una imagen a aws s3

Tags: nodejs, aws, graphql, amazon-s3

estoy intentando subir una imagen a traves de un mutation (graphql) pero al subir la imagen ingreso al link y me descarga la imagen pero al abrirla me dice "parece que el formato del archivo no es compatible".

agradeceria mucho sugerencias o detalles que pueda tener porque realmente la imagen si se guarda pero no por lo que veo, no correctamente

mi codigo de react js es este en el que envio el archivo a traves del mutation
saludos

```js
const [uploadFile, {data}] = useMutation(uploadFileMutation);
const onDrop = useCallback(
  async([file]) => {
    if (file) {
      setPreview(URL.createObjectURL(file));
      console.log("archivode", file)
      uploadFile({variables: {file: file}});
    }
  }, [uploadFile],
);
const {
  getRootProps,
  getInputProps,
  isDragActive,
  isDragAccept,
  isDragReject,
} = useDropzone({
  onDrop,
  accept: 'image/*',
  maxSize: 5120000,
});
```

y mi codigo desde node js es el siguiente

```js
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWSAccessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWSSecretKey,
  region: process.env.region,
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  region: process.env.region
});
// my default params for s3 upload
// I have a max upload size of 1 MB
const s3DefaultParams = {
  ACL: 'public-read',
  Bucket: process.env.bucket,
  Conditions: [
    ['content-length-range', 0, 5120000], // 1 Mb
    {
      acl: 'public-read'
    },
  ],
};
// the actual upload happens here
const handleFileUpload = async file => {
  const {
    path
  } = await file;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    s3.upload({
        ...s3DefaultParams,
        Body: "stream",
        Key: `images/${path}`,
      },
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('error uploading...', err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log('successfully uploaded file...', data);
          resolve(data);
        }
      },
    );
  });
};

module.exports = {
  handleFileUpload
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu atributo **"Body"** parece no hacer referencia al archivo que deseas subir a S3. Según la API de S3 el atributo Body pude ser de tipo **Buffer**, **Typed Array**, **Blob**, **String**, **ReadableStream**. Intenta pasar la referencia del archivo con ese tipo de dato.

También agrega el atributo **ContentType** con el mime type de la imagen que estas subiendo, por ejemplo: **"ContentType":"image/jpeg"**. De esa forma podrás ver la imagen en el navegador.